# Unable to close mergDataGridScroller in iOS

Tags: ios, livecode

This is what I'm trying to do: I've got two mergDataGridScrollers on top of each other. If I turn one of them invisible and scroll the other, I'm scrolling the invisible scroller because 1) it's not scrolling the intended scroller and 2) I can see the scrollbar of the invisible scroller scrolling.

So, I tried dispatching a "closeControl" to the invisible scroller, but that did not get sent because I think the command is private. Any suggestions on how to work with two overlapping iOS scrollers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there's a couple of bugs in mergDataGridScroller... I'll try and get a new version up ASAP

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used mergDataGridScrollers but have used scrollers in iOS with groups - and in an app where I wanted an iOS scroller to slide on and off the screen I had to delete it, slide off the group behind the scroller and slide the group on again and recreate the scroller when I wanted it back. Showing and hiding the scroller didn't cut it for me (as you describe on a device if you do a swipe where the scroller was you'll see the scrollbar) - you'll presumably have to delete and create the scrollers anyway on leaving/entering cards on iOS.

Comment: Interesting that you both had to both delete the scroller and move the group off-screen. I will look into this and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Todd, I only had to move the group off-screen because I wanted a slide-off-screen effect - but if I had made the group invisible without deleting the scroller I think I would have got the same effect you are experiencing - but it sounds like Monte is on the case for you...